Confused on how to prove the nature of this isolated singularity
$f(z) = \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{z}}}{z^2-\frac{π^2}{4}}$
I usually firstly try to expand it, in order to see if the number of terms in the principal part is finite, infinite etc.. but I always hit a dead end.
For this particular example, the isolated singularities are at $z=0, z=\frac{π}{2}, z=-\frac{π}{2}$.
I'm aware of how to prove the $π$ and $-π$ are poles but not what nature $z=0$ is. My professor expanded just the $e^{-\frac{1}{z}}$, and showed the terms in the principal part are infinite, hence it is an essential singularity.
I thought you had to expand the whole $f(z)$ instead of just the exponential to see the nature of the singularity, which is why I'm really confused.

I think you mean $z = 0$, $z = \pi/2$, and $z = -\pi/2$.

Yes, in principle you should expand everything. The argumentation can be completed in the following way. Let me call $f(z)=e^{-1/z}$ and $g(z)=z^2-\pi^2/4$, for short and since all it matters is that $f$ has an isolated-essential at $z=0$ and $g$ is regular there. Since the singularity of $f/g$ is isolated, then it is either essential or there is a $K$ such that $h(z)=z^Kf(z)/g(z)$ is regular at $z=0$. Then $h(z)g(z)=z^Kf(z)$ is regular at $z=0$, since it is a product $hg$ of two regular at $z=0$. But this implies that $f$ has at most a pole of order $\leq K$ at $z=0$.

Restricting to $z$ near $\pi/2$, the numerator is some boring holomorphic function, taking values in some small interval of $\mathrm{e}^{-2/\pi}$, so contributes nothing to the nature of the singularity.
$$  f(z) = \mathrm{e}^{-1/z} \left( \frac{1}{\pi}(z-\pi/2)^{-1} - \frac{1}{\pi^2} + \cdots \right)  \text{.}  $$
Similarly for $z$ near $-\pi/2$.
$$  f(z) = \mathrm{e}^{-1/z} \left( \frac{-1}{\pi}(z+\pi/2)^{-1} - \frac{1}{\pi^2} - \cdots \right)  \text{.}  $$
For $z$ near $0$, the denominator is some boring holomorphic function with values near $-\pi^2/4$, so contributes nothing to the nature of the singularity.  The numerator, however, isn't even continuous.
\begin{align*}
\lim_{z \rightarrow 0^{-}} f(z) &= \frac{-4}{\pi^2} \lim_{z \rightarrow 0^{-}} \mathrm{e}^{-1/z} = -\infty  \\
\lim_{z \rightarrow 0^{+}} f(z) &= \frac{-4}{\pi^2} \lim_{z \rightarrow 0^{+}} \mathrm{e}^{-1/z} = 0  \\  
\end{align*}
So the analysis is entirely in terms of what the numerator is doing.
In a different setting, where both the numerator and denominator contribute to the singularity at a particular value of $z$ (random example: $\mathrm{e}^{-1/z}/z$), then you would need to expand everything.

All you are saying in so many words, is "it is true because it is". The sentence "So the analysis is entirely in terms of what the numerator is doing." is what they need a proven.

@ameg : "I thought you had to expand the whole f(z) instead of just the exponential to see the nature of the singularity" is not what you are saying.  I have explained how to see the nature of the singularity with partial expansion.

@EricTowers Okay I'm following but, is there a way quick to tell if the numerator and denominator contribute to some singularity? Why does my denominator being a holomorphic function mean it doesn't contribute to the $z=0$ singularity?

@ameg Do you have an answer you could share with me? To try to get me to understand when expand the whole function and when you dont have to?

@EricTowers OH wait I think I understand. With your example, the singularity at $z=0$ appears in both the numerator and denominator, so in this case you have to expand the whole function. Alternatively, in cases where the singularity only appears in 1 part of the function, you can just expand that part.

@kiwizor : Sorry to keep you in suspense...  Your last comment is right on target.

@kiwizor : A fussy detail is that this discussion is for rational expressions.  Expresions with different structure may require a similar pattern of thought, but different mechanics.  For instance, $$ \frac{1}{z} + \mathrm{e}^{-1/z} \text{,}$$ which can be analyzed by combining these into a single division expression and can be analyzed by expanding both separately then adding them together (and probably can be analyzed in other ways).
